# EXC_BREAKPOINT when view loads the 2nd time in swift

Tags: ios, swift

my app is crashing when I load the view second time. When app open it doesnt crash. If I  click on my home menue when the app is opened it loads then after sometimes its crashing. These are the lines it shows the exception.
[image]

[image]

[image]

What is the reason for this? in my console it shows `atal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. What is the reason for this? Please help me.Thanks

Comment: The view "scrollMostWanted" is probably nil... you are not properly handling that optional. you can add "guard scrollMostWanted != nil else {return}" at the top of the function maybe. Or any other logic that works the best for you

Comment: I read it. I can't understand why its not crashing first time and why only crashing in second time?

Comment: Because it is not nil the first time... Are you removing the view? It is difficult to say based on your screenshots. It is better to submit the code :).

Comment: Thanks @Sajjon No I am not removing the view